# change the status of a test result after it is executed in TestNG

Tags: testng

Is it possible to change the status of a test result from @AfterClass method.
My requirement is to run some UI tests using @test tag and I need to validate the DB for all those tests in the @AfterClass method, since the DB is taking a while to get updated.

Comment: Cannot understand what your issue is?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in AfterClass, but you can utilize a listener to do this.  Try out IInvokedMethodListener.  Implement the following method : `public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult)`

The result object can be set here to whatever value, based on some checks (`testResult.setStatus(status)`).  Note this would be executed after every method.