# How can I fail a TestNG test within a listener

Tags: testing, testng

Is there a way to, from within an ITestListener implementation, actually fail a test that has already "passed" successfully?

My use case is this: I run all of the tests in my suite and then, at the end of the suite, perform some additional actions. As a result of these actions, I would like for tests that previously "passed" to now be marked as failures.

From within my listener (which is extends `TestListenerAdapter`), I am calling:

```
result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
result.setThrowable(t);
```

on some ITestResult objects. Elsewhere in the listener, I have overridden `onFinish` like so:

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(final ITestResult result) {
    super.onTestFailure(result);

    // TODO: This is updating the state of the test, but NOT causing it to fail
    Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
}
```

When I fail the test, the callback is being executed. The `Throwable` is added to the test result. Everything happens as I expected it to.

However, both the generated report and the build output are incorrect:

```
[testng] ===============================================
[testng] <redacted>Tests
[testng] Total tests run: 51, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
[testng] ===============================================
```

Despite the fact that 3 of these test results are being updated as failures:

[image: Nonsensical report output]

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know TestNG enough, but what happens when you just throw an exception inside the listener?

Comment: Throwing an exception from inside the listener "works" in the sense that the suite fails, which is essentially what I'm trying to do. What I'm doing now is accumulating the failures (and their causes) as shown above, and then throwing a runtime exception if the failure count is > 0. I'm just worried that this is a tricky way to do things that will ultimately break if I upgrade my TestNG version.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with changing the status from FAILURE to SKIP with this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158094) using IInvokedMethodListener.

The afterInvocation method, where the status can be changed, will not be invoked after the whole test suite completes but after each test method.